# Calculate probabilities and expected value $\mathbb E(X)$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Let $(Ω, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space, given two independent random variables $X, Y$, which can take the value $0$ or $1$.

Let $\mathbb P(X=0) = p,\mathbb P(Y=0) = q$, with $p, q ∈ [0,1]$.
Additionally, we have the random variable $Z = 2(X+Y) \mod 3$

Calculate all the single probabilities of $Z$ and the expected value $\mathbb E(Z)$.

Comment: Well, $Z$ can only have two values, $0$ or $2$. You could find the probabilities $P(Z=0)$  and $P(Z=2)$ by considering the combinations of $X$ and $Y$ that result in these.

Comment: @MattiP. $Z$ can be $1$ as well... in the event that $X=1$ and $Y=1$.  But really... the problem is otherwise identical to the problem of looking at it if it were looking at the random variable $T=X+Y$... the only distinction is that when $Z=1$ this corresponds with $T=2$ and when $Z=2$ this corresponds to $T=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply definitions and you are done.  Recognize that $2(0+0)\equiv 0\pmod{3}$, that $2(0+1)\equiv 2\pmod{3}$, that $2(1+0)\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ and that $2(1+1)\equiv 1\pmod{3}$.  Continue using the relationship between $Z$ and the joint distribution for $X,Y$, and apply what you know about independent random variables.

$Pr(Z=0) = Pr(X=0,Y=0)=Pr(X=0)\cdot Pr(Y=0) = pq$

$Pr(Z=1) = Pr(X=1,Y=1)=Pr(X=1)\cdot Pr(Y=1)=\dots$

$Pr(Z=2) = \dots$

$E[Z] = 0\cdot Pr(Z=0) + 1\cdot Pr(Z=1)+2\cdot Pr(Z=2) = 0\cdot pq + 1\cdot (\dots)+\dots$

Fill in the missing information.

Comment: so would it be pq, qp and pp+qq?

Comment: @huzuz No.  $Pr(Z=1)=Pr(X=1,Y=1)=Pr(X=1)\cdot Pr(Y=1)=(1-Pr(X=0))\cdot(1-Pr(Y=0))=(1-p)(1-q)$.  Nowhere did it suggest in this problem that $1-p=q$.  Although that is sometimes common when talking about a probability $p$ to give a name to its complementary value $1-p$ and to name that complementary value $q$, it is not happening here.  We instead gave the name $q$ to something unrelated to $p$.

Comment: Sorry, but i dont quite understand. It states that P(X=0) = p and p,q ∈[0,1]. So why isnt P(X=1) = q? Since there are only two options 1 and 0.

Comment: Because $q$ is the name that we have given to $P(Y=0)$ which may or may not be at all related to the number $p$.

Comment: If you prefer... in order to avoid the unnecessary habits of thinking that $q=1-p$... let us instead call $Pr(X=0)$ the variable $p_x$ instead... and then we can call the unrelated value $Pr(Y=0)$ the variable $p_y$ instead... would that make more sense to you?  There is no reason to assume that $p_y=1-p_x$

Comment: oh. I understand! Thank you!